# How to add new variable in existing data frame in R

Tags: r

I need to add a new variable in existing data frame and that new variable should have one value in first half rows and other value in second half row. Ex: my new variable name is "Condition" in existing data frame which has 100 rows,if i need to add "Dry" in first 50 rows and "Cool" in next 50 rows.
I tried this, but it is adding "Dry" in all 100 rows as shown below:

```
first.condition <- data.frame(condition=rep("Dry", nrow(data.combined_new)/2), data.combined_new[,])
```

Comment: Try `df1$Condition <- rep(c("Dry", "Cool"), each = 50)`

Comment: it worked, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The `x` argument of `rep` can take a `vector` of `length` greater than or equal to 1.  So, if the number of rows of the data is 100 and want to equally replicate 'Dry' and 'Cool' where the first 50 would be 'Dry', then use the `each` argument

```
df1$Condition <- rep(c("Dry", "Cool"), each = 50)
```